# IIS 8 - How to allow local IIS web server access to multiple users

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a Win 2012 server with IIS 8 running on that. Also installed Management Service with Remote Access allowed.

Another admin-user account is used to set up few default websites and now when I login to the same server using my admin-user account, I cannot see anything in the IIS.

I have tried connecting to server as localhost and with computer name as well but not allowing me to connect.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue -

There is a firewall implemented for the domain users to access. And when I tried to login as an Admin who is not permitted by firewall, I am just able to access the machine and internally my IIS component is not able to connect with the localhost or local server.